# pyqt QFileSystemModel rowCount

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I've seen posts about QFileSystemModel rowCount not working as expected ([ex1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544645/qfilesystemmodel-rowcount-does-not-work-as-expected), [ex2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658467/my-qfilesystemmodel-doesnt-work-as-expected-in-pyqt/2659123#2659123)), but I seem to be missing something.  The following code always reports a rowCount of 1 even though the list shows more..even after waiting 10 seconds.  What am I missing here?

```
import os, sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class TestWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.AllEntries | QtCore.QDir.Hidden | QtCore.QDir.NoDot)
        self.path = os.path.expanduser('~')
        self.model.setRootPath(self.path)
        view = QtWidgets.QListView()
        view.setModel(self.model)
        view.setRootIndex(self.model.index(self.path))
        self.setCentralWidget(view)
        self.model.directoryLoaded.connect(self._loaded)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10000, self._really_loaded)

    def _loaded(self):
        print('_loaded', self.path, self.model.rowCount())  # Always returns 1 here? even though there are more rows displayed

    def _really_loaded(self):
        print('_really_loaded', self.path, self.model.rowCount())  # 10 seconds later...Always returns 1 here? even tho there are more rows displayed


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = TestWindow()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

...for sanity..here's the same code as with pyqt4 with same result

```
import os, sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class TestWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.model = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.AllEntries | QtCore.QDir.Hidden | QtCore.QDir.NoDot)
        self.path = os.path.expanduser('~')
        self.model.setRootPath(self.path)
        view = QtGui.QListView()
        view.setModel(self.model)
        view.setRootIndex(self.model.index(self.path))
        self.setCentralWidget(view)
        self.model.directoryLoaded.connect(self._loaded)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10000, self._really_loaded)

    def _loaded(self):
        print('_loaded', self.path, self.model.rowCount())  # Always returns 1 here? even though there are more rows displayed

    def _really_loaded(self):
        print('_really_loaded', self.path, self.model.rowCount())  # 10 seconds later...Always returns 1 here? even tho there are more rows displayed


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = TestWindow()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass the index of the item you want to analyze, if you want to know how many items you have, use the index that returns `setRootPath()`.

```
import os, sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class TestWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.AllEntries | QtCore.QDir.Hidden | QtCore.QDir.NoDot)
        self.path = os.path.expanduser('~')
        self.parentIndex  = self.model.setRootPath(self.path)
        view = QtWidgets.QListView()
        view.setModel(self.model)
        view.setRootIndex(self.model.index(self.path))
        self.setCentralWidget(view)
        self.model.directoryLoaded.connect(self._loaded)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10000, self._really_loaded)

    def _loaded(self, path):
        print('_loaded', self.path, self.model.rowCount(self.parentIndex))  # Always returns 1 here? even though there are more rows displayed

    def _really_loaded(self):
        print('_really_loaded', self.path, self.model.rowCount(self.parentIndex))  # 10 seconds later...Always returns 1 here? even tho there are more rows displayed


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = TestWindow()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you so much!..seems obvious now that you point it out, but not sure I would have ever figured that out!!